dockerを起動するとWiFi接続が切れます。
お世話になります。
現在、dockerを起動すると、WiFiの接続が切れる状態です。
アプリを立ち上げた時点で接続が切れます。
PCの再起動を何度か試すとWi-Fiに接続されますが、根本的な原因がわかっていません。
調べてみましたが、このような事例の記事がなく、解決できていない状況です。
もし何かわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

本家の方で似た質問をしている方がいました。 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42533298/ 回答するには少し情報が不足しているので、docker network inspect bridge の出力などを貼り付けてもらえると良いかと思います。あわせて Docker のバージョンやホスト OS についての情報があると推測しやすいです。

OS の情報と docker version の実行結果も合わせて欲しいです。[edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

ありがとうございます。確認後追加します。
